# jQuery Datepicker setDate showing incorrect date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar

The calendar should be showing Oct 19, 2016, but it keeps showing Oct 18, 2016. I can't figure out why!

```
$('#datepickerDateReceived').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
}).datepicker(
        'setDate', new Date('2016-10-19')
    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rt3nC/34/

Comment: Seems to be working for me, on your jsFiddle

Comment: its showing all good for me too

Comment: It is showing Oct 18, 2016 for me. I believe the problem is dependent on the current time.
For me it is 15:51 EST.
If I change the code to 'setDate', new Date('2016-10-19 00:00'), it works correctly.

Comment: The problem is probably due to time zones.

Comment: It is a problem with time-zones like @Barmar said.
Try the following date constructions. javascript seems to create the date at midnight at GMT 0, then adjusts it for the equivalent timezone.
`new Date('2016-10-19');`
>Tue Oct 18 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
`new Date('2016-10-19 00:00');`
>Wed Oct 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01")  are treated as UTC, not local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that date strings are parsed as UTC 0, not local time-zone. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

To fix it, just add a time to your date string

```
$('#datepickerDateReceived').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
}).datepicker(
        // Initialize the date to be 00:00 local timezone on October 19, 2016
        'setDate', new Date('2016-10-19 00:00')
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not work in Safari:
$('#datepickerDateReceived').datepicker('setDate', new Date('2016-10-19 00:00'));

I had to put it this way to make it work in Safari:
$('#datepickerDateReceived').datepicker('setDate', new Date('2016-10-19 00:00'.replace(/\s/, 'T')));